# Read Byte[] as unsigned short Java

Tags: java

I need to read a byte array of 16 bits as unsigned short number, and Java doesn't support unsigned short type.
So how can i do it?? Please help!!

Comment: A byte array of 16 bits?  So it's an array of length 2?

Comment: I think you mean convert, not read, right?  So, convert two bytes into a single integer value?  The trick is that you will need to store it as an `int`, not a `short`.

Comment: The `char` datatype is essentially an unsigned `short`. But the most common technique is to use an `int`.

Comment: @glowcoder: shorts are two chars

Comment: @mkb shorts are 2 bytes, chars are two bytes. Read up on it at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Huh, good thing I don't do Java for a living :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have it available as binary data from a non-Java source that you must read and work with the values in Java:
Read it as a (signed) `short`, and then convert it to `int` as follows:

```
int intVal = shortVal >= 0 ? shortVal : 0x10000 + shortVal
```

You cannot represent all values of an unsigned short in a short, but in an int, you can.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you HAVE to use an unsigned short, but in case you don't, you can always use a char to hold an unsigned short. Take a look at this article that gives a simple overview

http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at

[org.apache.commons.io.EndianUtils.readSwappedUnsignedShort](https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/EndianUtils.html#readSwappedUnsignedShort%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29)